# Raspberry Pi Voltage Input

Tags: pi-2

I know Raspberry Pi can get 4.75-5.25 Volts as input but will it be OK with 5.3V?

Comment: Anything above 6v will destroy it. I think 5.3v should work just fine.

Comment: The voltage may drop on load, ie, when you connect it to the Pi. Anything above may be more dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Pi will be perfectly fine.  The Pi itself will be fine up to just less than 6V.

The 5V +/- 5% range is really to protect attached USB devices not the Pi.

I regularly measure 5.7V on my Pi's power supply.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! .. So ARE U SHURE 5.3V 2A will be good? i have a OEM Samsung charger and cable ( not a cheape chinese replica)

Comment: Absolutely, as long as it is accurately labelled.  When you can measure the voltage at the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

The supply voltage is 5V ±5%. This allows some variation and either extreme is not ideal. 5.3V is +6% (why do you think this is the input) and is **unlikely to cause any damage** as the Pi has over voltage protection, but is unlikely to be triggered (depending on the tolerance of other components). Potentially this may increase current and increase the risk of the poly fuse opening.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i bought Samsung OEM charger that supply 5.3V and 2A (that what it's says on it..) should i be afraid to use it?

Comment: Many modern phone chargers may not work! They are not designed to supply a constant voltage, but to rapidly charge batteries, and the voltage can fall as low as 3.6V.